# Golang load json data into Bigquery

Tags: json, go, google-bigquery

New to Go, trying to load json data below into Bigquery, I know it's not valid json format, which is also the issue I got.

```
[{"Name": "A", "Age": 11}, {"Name": "B", "Age": 22}]
```

I've managed to load only one record but couldn't figure out how to load multiples.

And I am **trying to avoid** that save data to json file then load from file. Also `client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID).Inserter()` requires table exist first, which is also not ideal for me, wondering is it possible to load with **loader**? Cheers

Here is my sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
)

type bqSchema struct {
    Name    string
    Age     int
}

func uploadJSONTruncate(projectID, datasetID, tableID, dataString string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    schema, err := bigquery.InferSchema(bqSchema{})
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.InferSchema: %v", err)
    }

    rs := bigquery.NewReaderSource(strings.NewReader(dataString))
    rs.FileConfig.SourceFormat = bigquery.JSON
    rs.FileConfig.Schema = schema
    loader := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID).LoaderFrom(rs)
    loader.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteTruncate
    loader.CreateDisposition = bigquery.CreateIfNeeded

    job, err := loader.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if status.Err() != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("job completed with error: %v", status.Err())
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    projectID := "dummy-project"
    datasetID := "dummy-dataset"
    tableID := "testTable"
    // dataString := `{"Name": "B", "Age": 222}`
    dataString := `[{"Name": "A", "Age": 11}\n{"Name": "B", "Age": 22}]`

    err := uploadJSONTruncate(projectID, datasetID, tableID, dataString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: For your requirement, you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/latest). You can try by modifying the datastring as dataString := `{"Name": "A", "Age": 11} {"Name": "B", "Age": 22}`. Let me know if that helps.